# insert a dynamic list into a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a 2d matrix of size `n*n` and a dynamic list of size `1*n`

The list keeps on changing the values on every iteration. I want to keep updating my 2d matrix with the list values. Initially the matrix is a `0 matrix` of `n*n`.

How can I achieve it?

For Eg:

I have matrix a as :

```
[0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0

 0,  0 , 0, 0, 0]
```

My list has value during 1st iterations as :

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Matrix after this should look like:

```
[1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5

 0,  0 , 0, 0, 0]
```

for 2nd iteration, my list has value:

```
[5,6,7,8,9]
```

After 2nd iteration matrix should look like:

```
[1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5

 5,  6 , 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show an example in code. It's not really clear how a list with `n` values is tied to a matrix with `n * n` values. In other words, what do you mean by `updating`.

Comment: First a list cannot have a size `1*n`.  It may be a list with one element, another list of `len` `n`.  Or it may just be a list..  In the simplest case you should be able to do: `arr[i, :] = alist`

Comment: @hpaulj I have edited with an example

Comment: @Mark I have added an example

Comment: You should probably explain what you need this for, as there may be better ways to achieve the same. What you're asking for is easily achieved with what @hpaulj suggests - what have you tried yourself? What problem did you run into?

Comment: If you have a `list` it's probably faster and more convenient to append to a `list` and convert the final result to `numpy`. Btw: Your example is not a matrix, it's a 1-D array written in two rows. A [mre] would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you asked.
Here a bunch of code it may be useful to you

```
runTimes = 0 #keeps track of which execution you are
matrix = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
myList = [0,0,0,0,0]
while(True):
   print("MATRIX: %s"%(matrix))
   print("LIST: %s"%(myList))

   for i in range(0,len(myList)):
       myList[i] = input("Input: ") #Ask for user Input

   for i in range(0, len(myList)): #for the number of elements in the list
       matrix[runTimes][i] = myList[i] #set the values of the matrix equal to those of the list

   runTimes += 1
   if(runTimes==2): #if you reach the second execution and you're going for the third, set runTimes to 0
       runTimes = 0
```

In this way you'd have this output:

```
MATRIX: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
LIST: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Input: 1
Input: 2
Input: 3
Input: 4
Input: 5
MATRIX: [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
LIST: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
Input: 6
Input: 7
Input: 8
Input: 9
Input: 10
MATRIX: [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
LIST: ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
Input: 11
Input: 12
Input: 13
Input: 14
Input: 15
MATRIX: [['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
LIST: ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
```